# How to copy a file from one URL to another without storing on local machine

Tags: java, file, url, copy, vfs

I am developping a DeployIt-like application, where a file (for example a JAR) has to be copied from one server and pasted to another. The most important aspect of this is that it has to be done atomically, without intermediate environments (like localhost).

I have managed to copy a file from one server to the local machine and then to the target server, but this operation is time-consuming and we cannot afford that.

```
URL url = new URL(path);
File result = new File("C:\\" + fileName);
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, result); // copy to local machine
FileObject localFile = manager.resolveFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
FileObject remoteFile = manager.resolveFile(
            createConnectionString(hostname, username, password, remoteFilePath, f.getName()), createDefaultOptions());

remoteFile.copyFrom(localFile, Selectors.SELECT_SELF); // copy to target server
```

How can I do that in one step?

Comment: Do you have CLI access of these servers? If yes, Did you try scp/rsync?

Comment: You can't do this. Even if you don't "officially" store file on filesystem on localhost it must be whole downloaded on your machine and then sent to another server.

Comment: What APIs do you use? What is `FileUtils`? What is `FileObject`?

Comment: @user11153 sorry but that is wrong; you can use an in memory buffer to do that. This is not without risks though.

Comment: @fge Even with memory buffer, you are downloading piece by piece, but still eventually WHOLE (but not whole at once, yes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you can obtain an `InputStream` from the source socket and an `OutputStream` from the destination socket, you can use a method which will avoid copying into a file, such as:

```
public static void copyStream(final InputStream in, final OutputStream out)
    throws IOException
{
    final byte[] buf = new byte[32768]; // or more, or less; size appropriately
    int nrBytes;

    while ((nrBytes = in.read(buf)) != -1)
        out.write(buf, 0, nrBytes);

    out.flush();
}
```

However, before going this way and avoid a temporary file inbetween, consider what would happen if you had a short read or short write; how do the endpoints behave in this case?

Also, note that this method *does not* close either stream; you'll have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNC path to map drive(if you have access). It will be fast because it uses `CIFS` protocol which is fast. The syntax will be something like.

```
new File("//SERVER/some/path").toURI().toString() -> "file:////SERVER/some/path
```